# Custom Mongoid 4.0.0 _id that contains . (dot) can't be queried throught params (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a model, which overrides the `_id` attribute with the unique `url` attribute:

```
class Website
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ url }
  field :url, type: String
  validates_uniqueness_of :url
end
```

My controller is pretty standard:

```
class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @website = Website.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And the link generation in my view file, is:

```
Website.all.each do |website|
  %p= link_to website.url, website_path(:id => website._id)
```

So far so good. But let's say that I have a website with the `_id` `"example.com"`. When I click the link to `website_path(:id => "example.com")`, the params `:id` gets cut of before the `.`(dot). So, naturally I get this error:

```
Started GET "/websites/example.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-26 10:36:10 +0100
Processing by WebsitesController#show as 
  Parameters: {"id"=>"example"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=myapp_development collection=websites selector={"_id"=>"example"} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.5150ms

Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound - 
...
...
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a routing problem. From the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments):

> By default, dynamic segments don't accept dots - this is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within a dynamic segment, add a constraint that overrides this – for example, `id: /[^\/]+/` allows anything except a slash

So you need to adjust your route to something like this:

```
get '/websites/:id' => 'websites#show', :id => /[^\/]+/
# --------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

so that the Rails routing system won't think that the `.com` is a format extension like `.html`, `.js`, ...